# Wordpress site experiencing "Catchable Fatal Error"

Tags: php, wordpress, fatal-error

I have a fatal error showing on my Wordpress site and can't seem to figure it out. The site hasn't been touched and just started displaying this recently.

Website URL: https://www.ragtopsmotorcars.com/

Whats displayed:

> "Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be
> converted to string in
> /home/content/97/11215397/html/wp-includes/default-constants.php on
> line 135"

The values inside the default-constants.php on line 135 consist of

```
// full url - WP_CONTENT_DIR is defined further up
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-content');
```

What could be causing this error?

Comment: Sounds like you're using an outdated (or possible corrupted/broken) version of WordPress. `default-constants.php:135` as of WordPress 5.4.2  is `define( 'HOUR_IN_SECONDS', 60 * MINUTE_IN_SECONDS );`. I'd suggest updating or re-installing WordPress. Also, you may want to consider going into your `wp_options` table and making sure that your `siteurl` and `homeurl` values are set properly (they should be, since the site isn't redirecting anywhere funky)

Comment: I cannot access the admin panel in order to update it. How else can I go about it? I know it can be done through FTP but I can't access the plug ins to disable them.

Comment: If you can use ftp, you can disable a plugin by renaming the plugin folder in the plugins folder. This essentially removes it from the site because WP can't access it anymore and deactivates it, but when you name it back it should work the same as if it had been deactivated (after you reactivate it). Although I'm not sure how that helps with what @Xhynk suggested doing :)

Comment: @ConnorKenney if you have FTP Access you should just be able to download WordPress from wordpress.org, unzip it, and upload it manually